# How to enable Lets encrypt certificate for few sites on windows server

Tags: asp.net, ssl, windows-server-2012-r2

I got couple sites running on windows server 2012 r2. Sites are http at the moment and showing as not secure. I am just thinking how could I apply let's encrypt or ssl to make them secure. Without braking the sites. I have tried to look on google but could find the right way to do it.

if anyone got suggestions please drop a message. thanks

Comment: How you set this up? It very much similar to most sites. The site does need a public URL. So you can't really do this for a internal server (since their site has to be able to hit and talk to the public URL (or IP) address for this to work. (but, that's quite much the same for all security certificate setups.  Their site has some tools you can use for this purpose - and they work fine with asp.net sites.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool, this will help you install as many LetsEncrypt certificates as you want

https://www.win-acme.com/

Comment: ohh that looks exactly what i need, thanks, I Will try to use that.